# Remove tourists from vacation photos

Tags: image-processing

I just found this link: https://photoshoptrainingchannel.com/remove-tourists-stack-mode/

They used photoshop to remove the tourist from a series of photos. I was wondering if this is also possible in mathematica and if so, what functions to use?

Comment: [`Inpaint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inpaint.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article says to align photos and then take the median.

Use [`ImageAlign`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAlign.html) to align, take the [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html), use [`Median`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Median.html), convert back the data to an image using [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you :)!